# This hosted web app specifies one or more URLs that are not matched by sites you own.

Tags: google-search-console, chrome-web-store

I am trying to put in a hosted app in the chrome webstore.

I am getting an message

> This hosted web app specifies one or more URLs that are not matched by sites you own. If this app will be published for anyone to access, you must verify ownership of or association to sites to match all of the URLs listed below.
>
> For extents of the form *://example.com, you must own
>   http://example.com and https://example.com or have verified ownership
>   of or association to example.com at the domain level.
>
> Unmatched app urls:
>   *://demo.communities-360.com/ To verify your ownership of these websites, add the necessary websites using Google Webmaster Tools and
>   return here to complete this step.
>
> If the site already has an owner, you may request they grant you an
>   association which allows you to publish apps and extensions to the
>   Chrome Web Store on behalf of the site. You may request an association
>   in the verified website section below.

I am the verified owner of www.communities-360.com the parent domain. I can see that on my webmasters tool. How do i make chromestore understand i am the owner?

Comment: Wouldn't communities-360.com be the parent domain? WWW is just a subdomain unless there's some mix-up on what you have confirmed ownership for.

Comment: i am trying to add up demo.communities-360.com as the hosted app url which is the subdomain. I am confirmed owner of www.communities-360.com

Comment: i think the issue is that in my manifest file, i have the "urls": [
      "*://demo.communities-360.com/", Once i change the * to a http then it works